# pandas create one column equal to another if condition is satisfied

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas

I have two columns as below:

```
id, colA, colB
0, a, 13
1, a, 52
2, b, 16
3, a, 34
4, b, 946
etc...
```

I am trying to create a third column, `colC`, that is `colB` if `colA == a`, otherwise `0`.

This is what I was thinking, but it does not work:

```
data[data['colA']=='a']['colC'] = data[data['colA']=='a']['colB']
```

I was also thinking about using `np.where()`, but I don't think that would work here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What should be the value of colC if colB not == colA?

Comment: @luismf Oh good point. `0`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `loc` with a mask to assign:

```
In [300]:
df.loc[df['colA'] == 'a', 'colC'] = df['colB']
df['colC'] = df['colC'].fillna(0)
df

Out[300]:
   id colA  colB  colC
0   0    a    13    13
1   1    a    52    52
2   2    b    16     0
3   3    a    34    34
4   4    b   946     0
```

**EDIT**

or use `np.where`:

```
In [296]:
df['colC'] = np.where(df['colA'] == 'a', df['colC'],0)
df

Out[296]:
   id colA  colB  colC
0   0    a    13    13
1   1    a    52    52
2   2    b    16     0
3   3    a    34    34
4   4    b   946     0
```

Comment: thanks! thanks for also updating the edit after noticing the comment. I'll accept when SO lets me.

Comment: I've updated the first solution also, you'd have to call `fillna(0)` to replace the `NaN` values

Answer (score 1):

```
df['colC'] = df[df['colA'] == 'a']['colB']
```

should result in exactly what you want, afaik.

Then replace the NaN's with zeroes with `df.fillna(inplace=True)`